# Create an inhabited black hole

Tags: cosmology

Hello I was watching one of Isaac Arthur's videos about the end of time and i just got a crazy idea

Is it theoretically possible to "create" a "solar system" that would look like a supermasive black hole to ouside observers , but inside would be normal-ish, by plasing the most massive star in the universe at the center, then thousands or milions of main sequence stars orbiting it with 2 or more stars (at L points) on the same orbit?

Would you be able to get the mass high enough that the inner "solar system" would look like a black hole from the outside if you ignore problems with orbital stability and heat of such system?

My guess is no, but thought i'd ask 
Thanks

Comment: I don't understand how this could be perceived as a black hole. I mean, a million stars are not black. They shine.

Answer (score 4):

The misconception here is that with enough stars the gravitational pull would form an event horizon that would stopping light from escaping it.  If the light emitted by a star could leave it's surface heading out of the centre of mass, then it isn't an event horizon. If light can't escape, then the star is going to be ripped apart by the enormous gravitational pull it's experiencing.

Basically the same gravitational effects that would lead to a solar system appearing like a blackhole would lead to the destruction of said solar system.

Answer (score 2):

It is going to be hard to make thousands or millions of stars to orbit the central star, since largest stars are just hundreds of solar masses. Ie barycenter of this system would be outside its center, and the "central" star would rather orbit the system itself.

Also stable orbits do not exist inside event horizons, so such system is not physically possible. Anything inside event horizon will eventually end up in the singularity. Most likely extremely quickly too.

Comment: I see , thanks . Then how about a small black hole at the center , then have a red dwarm with a habitable planet orbiting that black hole way outside the event horizon , far enough to be in a stable orbit , then have few milion solar masses worth of stars orbiting further out.

Would this "enlarge" the event horizon to an outside observer to possibly hide the habitable planet due to the combined gravity of all those stars and the black hole ?

Since the stars orbit around you then their net gravity should be close to zero therefore you wouldn't actually be inside the event horizon?

Comment: If you put that many stars close enough together General Relativity would take you far enough from normal Newtonian gravity that the stars could not orbit. They would fall in and collide within a few days.